# Different Blast tools

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I am currently looking for commercial vs. non-commercial blast tools. I've used several times the NCBI blast for my local blast searches but now I am looking for interesting alternatives. During my search I found some interesting results such as CUDA-Blast, GPU-Blast, WU-Blast, BlastStation2, mpiBlast and Turboblast. As anyone experiences with those tools? Or are there any similar tools such as BlastStation2 available, that I missed? Any important commercial or non-commercial blast tools I missed?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Beeth

Comment: Protip: for bioinformatics related questions, there is also http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check out http://www.sequenceserver.com
It's open source. It makes it really easy to rapidly set up a local BLAST server to which you get a web interface. (Meaning that you can share it with colleagues too).

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Cheers,

Yannick

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at the FASTA programs, which provide the same comparison functions, and more.  The FASTA programs can produce BLAST output, so analysis pipelines need minimal modification.

http://faculty.virginia.edu/wrpearson/fasta